# How to Remove all text leave only numbers in Memo

Tags: delphi

I need a button through the lines of the Same and look for letters, so deleting all the letters and leaving only the numbers

example:

```
fakestackoverflow;466546511
nulling;65496411
```

result:

```
;466546511
;65496411
```

Comment: You did not leaving only digits. AFAIK `;` is not a digit

Comment: @SirRufo put only to separate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not given a clear specification of which characters you want to keep, and which you want to omit. But in any case, it's preferable to write a general function to filter characters that filters based on caller provided criteria. Like this:

```
function Filter(const Input: string; const Keep: TFunc<Char, Boolean>): string;
var
  C: Char;
  N: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Input));
  N := 0;
  for C in Input do
    if Keep(C) then
    begin
      inc(N);
      Result[N] := C;
    end;
  SetLength(Result, N);
end;
```

I'm assuming that you are using traditional one-based string indexing.

Here's a demonstration of how to call the function:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Character;

function Filter(const Input: string; const Keep: TFunc<Char, Boolean>): string;
var
  C: Char;
  N: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Input));
  N := 0;
  for C in Input do
    if Keep(C) then
    begin
      inc(N);
      Result[N] := C;
    end;
  SetLength(Result, N);
end;

function IsNotLetter(C: Char): Boolean;
begin
  Result := not C.IsLetter;
end;

begin
  Writeln(Filter('fakestackoverflow;466546511', IsNotLetter));
  Writeln(Filter('nulling;65496411', IsNotLetter));
end.
```

**Output:**

```
;466546511
;65496411
```

You want to apply such a transformation to the content of a memo control. Do that like this:

```
Memo1.Text := Filter(Memo1.Text, IsNotLetter);
```

Comment: out of pure curiosity how come you do not use a regular expression?

Comment: @JensBorrisholt That would work well if you could specify the predicate using re syntax. But `IsLetter` is non-trivial in the Unicode world. Of course I've no real idea what the user is after. Perhaps the input text is ASCII. I don't know.

Comment: For Delphi 2010 and later versions that don't have RECORD HELPERs for built-in types, replace "not C.IsLetter" with "NOT TCharacter.IsLetter(C)"

Comment: @HEARTWARE No, one would replace `not` with `not`. There's not need to impose your letter case preferences on the rest of us. ;-)

Comment: I'm not "imposing" anything - no more than you are with your lower case.

Comment: @HEARTWARE It almost seemed as though you were recommending to future readers that they should change `not` to `NOT`. I'd be inclined to stick to the convention set out in the original answer. So, if I were to suggest in your answer that the set should be a set of specific 8 bit characters I'd recommend changing `SET OF CHAR` to `SET OF ANSICHAR`. Or perhaps `SET OF AnsiChar`, not being quite sure of your naming conventions. But certainly it would be wrong to suggest changing `SET OF CHAR` to `set of AnsiChar`. That's all I meant.

Comment: @HEARTWARE I think you've picked me up on that in past, and you were right to do so.

Comment: Point taken. I wasn't trying to "impose" anything - just writing it in the style I am using in my daily coding, but you're right, I should propably have adapted my coding style to match the original code...

Comment: @HEARTWARE No probs. It was meant light heartedly. Hence the ;-) Didn't want to start a long thread. Should probably have said nothing! Sorry!

Answer (score -2):

I use this function:

```
TYPE CharSet = SET OF CHAR;

FUNCTION KeepChars(CONST S : STRING ; CONST Z : CharSet) : STRING;
  VAR
    I   : Cardinal;

  BEGIN
    Result:='';
    FOR I:=1 TO LENGTH(S) DO IF S[I] IN Z THEN Result:=Result+S[I]
  END;
```

Limitation: Only works to keep 8-bit characters. If you want it to work properly in Unicode, you can use this instead:

```
FUNCTION KeepChars(CONST S,Keep : STRING) : STRING;
  VAR
    I   : Cardinal;

  BEGIN
    Result:='';
    FOR I:=1 TO LENGTH(S) DO IF POS(S[I],Keep)>0 THEN Result:=Result+S[I]
  END;
```

Limitation: Doesn't handle multi-word 16-bit characters properly.

Comment: Not if the memo has a lot of text and especially not if `Length(Keep)` is large.

Comment: Stroing "a lot of text" in a memo is a bad idea and wrong design in any case, so...

Comment: I'm glad you aren't designing my text editing tools then!!  ;-)  Otherwise I'd have to make sure that I never tried to edit text files that were large.

Comment: If I were to design a text editing tool, I wouldn't use a standard Memo to do it (just try to work with a multi-Mb file in NotePad to see the performance of this - insert a character at the first line and wait a second or two for it to appear). I would design my own edit control to handle it...